# Question about exporting data from Google Analytics to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have question regarding our data export from Google Analytics to BigQuery.

Specifically, I have a question about the generated tables events_* and events_intraday_*.

Question

I have a question about the time when the events_* table on BigQuery is created.
Currently, I think it is created "around 23~24pm JST on the next day".
However, for business purposes, we would like to make the data available "around 3~4am JST on the next day".
Is it possible to change this?

Confirmed Documents

- Bigquery
- GA4